# Scheme - using apply

Tags: function, object, scheme, apply

I received the following exercise as homework. I sat on it for hours without any success, so I have no choice but to use your help.

**Examples:**

```
(define m1 (cons "fixNumber" (lambda () 42)))

(define m3 (cons "add" (lambda (x y) (+ x y))))

(define myobj (create-obj (list m1 m2 m3)))

(myobj "fixNumber" '()) ;; => 42

(myobj "add" '(1 2)) ;; => 3

(myobj "myMethod" '()) ;; => "Error: no such method"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
(define (create-obj mlist)
  (lambda (method parms)
    (let ((func (assoc method mlist)))
      (if func
          (apply (cdr func) parms)
          "Error: no such method"))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I also have to write a function named 'override' which takes an object and a property and overrides the old property of the object with the new one. If the object has no method with the name of the new property then the given property is a new property of the newly created object. How can I edit an object in scheme?

Comment: for example:

(define myobj (create-obj (list  (cons "a" (lambda () 1)) (cons "b" (lambda (x) (+ x 2))))))



(define myobj (override myobj (cons "b" (lambda () 11))))

Comment: @user3451848 Please create a new question for this; you can always include a link to this one.