# Redefine an object

Tags: object, scheme

[Scheme - using apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514132/scheme-using-apply)

```
(define myobj (create-obj (list  (cons "a" (lambda () 1)) (cons "b" (lambda (x) (+ x 2))))))
(myobj "a" '()) ;; => 1
(myobj "b" '(1)) ;; => 3
(define myobj (override myobj (cons "b" (lambda () 11))))
(myobj "a" '()) ;; => 1
(myobj "b" '()) ;; => 11
```

I thought about something like:

```
((equal? (car property) "b")
   (object "b" '(1)))
```

instead of sending '(1) as parameter, maybe to send a help-function that will override the method...

```
 ((equal? (car property) "b")
 (object "b" (help-func)))
```

I got lost...

Comment: You cannot `define` the same binding twice in Scheme. You can `set!` it the second time.

Comment: We are not allowed to use SET!
Otherwise there is no point in question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for something like this:

```
(define (create-obj mlist)
  (lambda (method parms)
    (case method
      ((override) (set! mlist (cons parms mlist)))
      (else (let ((func (assoc method mlist)))
              (if func
                  (apply (cdr func) parms)
                  "Error: no such method"))))))

(define myobj (create-obj (list  (cons "a" (lambda () 1)) (cons "b" (lambda (x) (+ x 2))))))
(myobj "a" '()) ;; => 1
(myobj "b" '(1)) ;; => 3

(myobj 'override (cons "b" (lambda () 11)))
(myobj "a" '()) ;; => 1
(myobj "b" '()) ;; => 11
```

Alternatively, without `set!` but using a second binding:

```
(define (create-obj mlist)
  (lambda (method (parms null))
    (case method
      ((get) mlist)
      (else  (let ((func (assoc method mlist)))
               (if func
                   (apply (cdr func) parms)
                   "Error: no such method"))))))

(define (override obj func)
  (create-obj (cons func (obj 'get))))

(define myobj (create-obj (list  (cons "a" (lambda () 1)) (cons "b" (lambda (x) (+ x 2))))))
(myobj "a" '()) ;; => 1
(myobj "b" '(1)) ;; => 3

(define myobj2 (override myobj (cons "b" (lambda () 11))))
(myobj2 "a" '()) ;; => 1
(myobj2 "b" '()) ;; => 11
```

**EDIT** It appears that you're using `#lang r5rs`:

```
#lang r5rs

(define (create-obj mlist)
  (lambda (method parms)
    (case method
      ((get) mlist)
      (else  (let ((func (assoc method mlist)))
               (if func
                   (apply (cdr func) parms)
                   "Error: no such method"))))))

(define (override obj func)
  (create-obj (cons func (obj 'get '()))))

(define myobj (create-obj (list  (cons "a" (lambda () 1)) (cons "b" (lambda (x) (+ x 2))))))
(display (myobj "a" '()))  (newline) ;; => 1
(display (myobj "b" '(1))) (newline) ;; => 3

(define myobj2 (override myobj (cons "b" (lambda () 11))))
(display (myobj2 "a" '())) (newline) ;; => 1
(display (myobj2 "b" '())) (newline) ;; => 11 
(newline)
```

Comment: The only problem is that I can not use SET!

Comment: Then the second "object" must have a name other than `myobj`.

Comment: you are right. I was wrong - he has a different name. This way, how can I solve it without SET!

Comment: one more question - (params null). I got an error:
 #%plain-lambda: not an identifier in: (parms null)